# TCL 8.3 unlimited arguments in a function (proc)

Tags: function, tcl

I want to pass some arguments to a function but i dont know how many there gonna be. My function looks like this:

```
proc audit {wordcount blockstring} {
    puts "This is the wordcount: $wordcount"
    puts "This is the blockstring: $blockstring"
}
```

no how i call the function would be like this:

```
audit "10" "blue" "red and brown" "green and yellow"
```

So the problem here is, that TCL barks at me with the 'called "audit" with too many arguments' phrase. Usually i would just us a single argument and go with the index like this:

```
proc audit {blockstring} {
    puts "This is the wordcount: $wordcount"
    puts "This is the blockstring: $blockstring"
    set wordcount [lindex $blockstring 0]
    set blockstring [lrange $blockstring 1 end]
}
```

But the problem with this solution is, that i dont have a way to differenciate the colors as they are then parsed as one list.

I know that there are solutions with [split] where i can put a character in between the colors like: `audit "10" "blue'red and brown'green and yellow"`

But other circumstances have it, that i can only provide the arguments like this: `"blue" "red and brown" "green and yellow"`
and there are sometimes 2 colors, and sometimes there are 50 colors. So how can i change the function in a way that it accepts "unlimited" arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the special [`args` variable](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.html) as the function argument. It will capture unlimited number of arguments as a list:

```
proc unlimited {args} {
    set wordcount [lindex $args 0]
    set blocklist [lrange $args 1 end]

    set i 1
    foreach x $blocklist {
        incr i
        if {[regexp {\w+ and \w+} $x]} {
            puts "argument $i has two colors: $x"
        } else {
            puts "argument $i has one color: $x"
        }
    }
}

# call with 2 args:
unlimited 10 red

# call with 5 args:
unlimited 55 blue green "yellow and purple" brown
```

Comment: This is the same i already posted with the `proc audit {blockstring} {` entry. But this way i dont have the possibility to differenciate the colors as there could be 2 colors in one argument.

Comment: Try it, it's not the same as your single blockstring argument.

Comment: By the way Tcl 8.3 is *ancient*, have you considered updating?  It doesn't make a difference for this issue though.

Comment: This allows you to differentiate between one and two colors. Just check if the argument contains the word `and`

Comment: @MarioJost modified the example code to showcase processing your color list

Comment: I just tested it and bloody hell does it work. Thank you very much. It gives back like an array of arguments nicely seperated.

Comment: Sadly, this runs on a Cisco IOS-XE operating system and i am at the mercy of cisco to update the TCL version.

Comment: I feel your pain. Several years ago I was working with an object database that embedded version 8.0.